# VBA Subscript out of range - error 9 in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting  this error while trying to run my code, what's funny is that the error doesn't everytime I run it on my pc, sometimes the code runs and other times it won't run, I tried to use Cells() instead of range, but it gives me the same error and I don't know why.
Here's my code:

```
Dim wbOrigen As Workbook, _
wsOrigen As Excel.Worksheet, _
wsDestino As Excel.Worksheet, _
rngOrigen As Excel.Range, _
rngDestino As Excel.Range
Reporte = Application.Workbooks(1).Worksheets("Datos").Range("B2").Value

Set wbOrigen = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/" & Reporte & ".xlsx")
Set wbDestino = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/Tabla Maestra Invemer.xlsm")

ThisWorkbook.Activate

'Initial Data
Set wsOrigen = wbOrigen.Worksheets("DATOS INICIALES")
Set wsDestino = wbDestino.Worksheets("Datos")
```

Comment: Your code assumes that there is a sheet called "Datos" in the *first opened* workbook. (so it would never work for me for example because that would be my personal macro workbook)

Comment: `Workbooks(1)` Is a volatile way of referencing the workbook...

Comment: Try to replace `Application.Workbooks(1)` with `ThisWorkbook` if you mean the workbook the VBA code is written in. Also avoid `ActiveWorkbook` if possible. Make sure you know the difference between `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: FYI You'll get a *type mismatch* on the `Set wbOrigen` and `Set wbDestino` instructions, because these variables should be `As Excel.Workbook` (*workbook* being the object that contains *worksheets* and represents a .xlsx file).

Comment: Does `ThisWorkbook` (the host document for your VBA code) have the "Datos" sheet? If so, then you never need to dereference that `Workbook` object, it's always `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: Could someone share what the point of using *Excel.Oject* instead of just *Object* (in the declarations) is? (Similarly (not quite), by using `VBA.Array` instead of `Array` you can ensure that the array is zero-based.)

Comment: @VBasic2008 this would actually be a new quesition (and is off topic here) but I see no difference in `Excel.Oject` or `Oject` (both do the same). The first is just more specific and more reliable: If you name a user defined `Type Worksheet` (which is a bad idea, but actually you can) then `Dim t As Worksheet` would take the user defined type and `Excel.Worksheet` ensures that Excel's worksheet type is used.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typical error, when you use `ActiveWorkbook` or have more than one workbook opens at the given time.

1. Try to avoid `ActiveWorkbook` you can type `ThisWorkbook` instead
2. Close all other workbooks, if you have them open (or click on the workbook, where the VBA code is executed).